# Bash using sed to find symbols

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am using `sed` to parse an xml file from yahoo.finance. the file contains a bunch of uninteresting information and all global stock symbols which i want to extract. It's a 1 liner xml file with a big amount of stock symbols which are represented like that:

```
symbol="VALUE"
```

i am using `sed` like this:

```
sed "s/.* symbol=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/" list_stocksymbols.xml >> ./tmpfile.txt
```

my output looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
WRG.AX
<!-- engine8.yql.bf1.yahoo.com -->
```

**problem**

as you can see only 1 symbol is extracted (WRG.AX).

**question**

how would i go about getting sed to write out all symbols?

**i tried**

```
sed "s/.* symbol=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/g" list_stocksymbols.xml >> ./tmpfile.txt
```

global flag, but it didnt work :/

**xml file extract **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="215" yahoo:created="2014-08-22T09:05:59Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results><industry id="112" name="Agricultural Chemicals">
        <company name="Adarsh Plant Protect Ltd" symbol="ADARSHPL.BO"/>
        <company name="Agrium Inc" symbol="AGU.DE"/><company name="Agrium Inc" symbol="AGU.TO"/>
        <company name="Agrium Inc." symbol="AGU"/>
        <company name="Aimco Pesticides Ltd" symbol="AIMCO.BO"/>
        <company name="American Vanguard Corp." symbol="AVD"/>
```

... and so on. The file is in 1 line only and not formatted like above.

** perl regex try **

```
perl -nle'print $& if m{(?<=symbol=")[^"]+}' list_stocksymbols
```

did also just bring out the first occurence

Comment: It probably does not work because you use the greedy `.*`. Try it with `.*?`.

Comment: @TimZimmermann this writes out the complete file again. sadly not the solution

Comment: Can you add a part of the XML file to your question, please?

Comment: **sed regex does not recognize** the non-greedy quantifier `?`.

Comment: Does it has to be accomplished with `sed`?

Comment: @TimZimmermann no :) im just looking for a simple solution and stumbled accross some similar stackoverflows and tried this. any other suggestion is welcome as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Eo 'symbol="[^"]+' yahoo.txt | cut -c 9-
```

This works for all the `grep` versions without `Perl` support (as in Mac OS X in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Also using only sed you could:

```
sed 's/.*symbol=\"//;s/\".*//' yahoo.txt
```